# using boost ptr_unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a class `ItemThreadingController` with `boost::ptr_unordered_map` where key is `id` of the thread, and value is a `boost::thread` with some task. I want to add and erase threads. Basically it's a primitive thread manager.

The question is - what is the correct way to use `ptr_unordered_map` - to declare and to get access to its elements? When I try like this

```
class ItemThreadingController
{
private:
boost::ptr_unordered_map<int, boost::thread> controllerMap;
long int id;
public:
ItemThreadingController() 
{
    id = -1;
}
int AddThread(void (*func)())
{
    boost::thread t(func);
    id++;
    controllerMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, t));
    return id;
}
void StopThread(long int id)
{
    controllerMap[id].interrupt();
    controllerMap[id].join();
    controllerMap.erase(id);
    cout<<"Thread "<<id<<"has stopped and erased!"<<endl;
}
~ItemThreadingController() {};
};
```

I've got several errors

```
error C2664: 'void boost::ptr_map_adapter<T,VoidPtrMap,CloneAllocator,Ordered>::insert<boost::type>(InputIterator,InputIterator)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::type' to 'boost::type'  518
error C2664: 'boost::ptr_map_iterator<I,F,S> boost::ptr_container_detail::associative_ptr_container<Config,CloneAllocator>::erase(boost::ptr_map_iterator<I,F,S>,boost::ptr_map_iterator<I,F,S>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::type' to 'boost::ptr_map_iterator<I,F,S>'   185
error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<C,F1,F2>'   63
error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<C,F1,F2>'   63
```

How to use it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::ptr_unordered_map<A, B>` can be seen as an equivalent to `std::unordered_map<A, std::unique_ptr<B>>`. It aims to simplify the memory management on deletion and element removal.

When you're doing this:

```
boost::thread t(func);
id++;
controllerMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, t));
```

It cannot work the map expects a pointer as `pair::second`.

Moreover, I am not sure `boost::ptr_XXX` mimics exactly `std::XXXX` and I do not think there is a `boost::ptr_unordered_map<A, B>::insert()` overload taking a `std::pair<A, B*>`. But at least you have an overload  `boost::ptr_unoreder_map<A, B>::insert(A&, B*);`.

Comment: And what I should insert? When I send `&t` as a second parameter it doesn't work either

Comment: @user1432980 It does not work because `t` is defined on the stack and taking the address of a temporary is bad. But it will certainly compile. At least if you use the `insert(key, value*)` overload, because I do not think there is an insert `std::pair<>` overload.